# Three.Js : Wrong quaternion rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, kinect, quaternions

My input is a jsonObject skeleton from a kinect stream. The goal is to measure the angle of the skeleton on the xz plane, and rotate the whole skeleton on the y axis so that no matter the stance, it is always "facing" the camera
I have a function that calculates the angle of the person by the hips coordinates
Like this:

```
 function GetHipRotation(skeleton)
 {
   var   leftHip = skeleton.Joints[SkeletonJointEnum.HipLeft];
   var   rightHip = skeleton.Joints[SkeletonJointEnum.HipRight];
    var zL=leftHip.Position.Z;
        var zR=rightHip.Position.Z;
        var D=zR-zL;
        var W=rightHip.Position.X-leftHip.Position.X ; 
        return Math.atan(D/W);       
}
```

and a  function to create a quaternion and rotate the skeleton on this angle :

```
function RotateSkeleton(skeleton)
{

var rot_angle=usrAngle=GetHipRotation(skeleton);
for (var i = 0; i < skeleton.Joints.length; i++) {
    //create vector R, the axis of rotation (y-axis in our case)
    var R= new THREE.Vector3 (0, 1, 0); //THIS IS THE Y AXIS//      
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Create my quaternion and do the rotation using R axis and the Angle 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     var skelquat = new THREE.Quaternion();
    skelquat.setFromAxisAngle( R, rot_angle ); // INANGLE HERE
    jointVector3=new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
    jointVector3=OriginJointVector[i];
            rotJointVector.push(jointVector3);
    rotJointVector[i].applyQuaternion(skelquat);
    rotX=rotJointVector[i].x;
    rotY=rotJointVector[i].y;
```

Then I try to draw it and here everything goes wrong..

```
    context2.beginPath();
    context2.arc(parseFloat(rotX) * 200 + 300 , parseFloat(rotY) * -200 + 200, 4, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    //draw joint number over the joint
    context2.strokeText(i,parseFloat(rotX) * 200 + 300 , parseFloat(rotY) * -200 + 200,200);

    context2.closePath();
    if(skeleton.Joints[i].TrackingState === 2)
        context2.fillStyle = "#cc0066";
    else
        context2.fillStyle = "#ff9900";             
    context2.fill();
}
 }
```

The skeleton doesnt seems to be responding accordingly. I would expect minimal "revolving" action but still, when I input a rotating man, it still appears rotating instead of "autocorrecting" the position, even when I put in a constant angle of rotation.Any  ideas?